# Ui-inspector tools for expo (react native app) for debugging styling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I'm new in react native development. The first issue i faced is that i didn't found the way to inspect my ui elements.

I am using expo-cli to run react native app in my android phone.
and I didn't found the way to debug or inspect my ui elements.

Can anybody Please help me regarding this.
because i think there is definitely a way to inspect ui-elements in react native as we do for react-web-app with chrome inspector tools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Developer Mode`

React Native includes some very useful tools for development: remote JavaScript debugging in Chrome, live reload, hot reloading, and an element inspector similar to the beloved inspector that you use in Chrome. It also performs bunch of validations while your app is running to give you warnings if you're using a deprecated property or if you forgot to pass a required property into a component, for example.

[image: step image]

a link with a detailed description of [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/development-mode/)